# Create immutable HashMap from Cargo build script

Tags: rust, hashmap, immutability, rust-cargo

I'm using something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50553370/how-do-i-use-include-str-for-multiple-files-or-an-entire-directory/50554062#50554062) to load some file data into a Rust binary. I'd like this data to be stored in a HashMap, so I'm able to search by key in the main program. However, I'm not sure how to do it in a way that ensures this data is immutable.

From the vector previously defined in `build.rs`, I assume I could do something like this in `main.rs`:

```rust
const ALL_THE_FILES: &[(&str, &[u8])] = &include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/all_the_files.rs"));

fn main () {
  let all_the_files_hashmap: HashMap<&str, &[u8]> = ALL_THE_FILES.iter().cloned().collect();
  // ...
}
```

Is there any way to construct this HashMap directly from `build.rs` and load it to a `const` in `main.rs`? If I replace the tuple-vector approach used in the linked answer with a HashMap definition iterating with something like `data.insert(<key>,<value>);`, can I load this into `main.rs` with `include!` in the same way, keeping the HashMap immutable?

Thanks a lot!
Regards

Comment: You could go with: https://github.com/sfackler/rust-phf - which is compile-time, Vs `lazy_static` which is runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to create a global read-only hashmap is to use [`lazy_static`](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/1.4.0/lazy_static/#example):

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

use std::collections::HashMap;

const ALL_THE_FILES: &[(&str, &[u8])] = ...;

lazy_static! {
    static ref FILE_TO_DATA: HashMap<&'static str, &'static [u8]> = {
        let mut m = HashMap::new();
        for (file, data) in ALL_THE_FILES {
            m.insert(*file, *data);
        }
        m
    };
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", FILE_TO_DATA.get("foo").unwrap());
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3b01d0fc0b722e443df3d6b8145b1e55)

You could move this logic into code generated by `build.rs`, but it would be much less obvious what's going on.