# How do I run tests using the root directory of the crates' workspace as the working directory?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a set of Cargo crates in a workspace which is structured as below:

```
project1
|- app-context
|  |- src/lib.rs
|  |- Cargo.toml
|- config
|  |-development.toml
|Cargo.toml
```

I am running a function in `lib.rs` using rust tests which print the folders and files in the folder using

```rust
let paths = fs::read_dir("./").unwrap();

for path in paths {
    println!("Name: {}", path.unwrap().path().display())
}
```

The output I get is  `src` & `Cargo.toml`. But the result I expect is `app-context` & `config`.
What am I doing wrong here?
How do I set the default working directory to the folder containing all my crates rather than pointing to a particular workspace?

Comment: I have fixed the nomenclature in the question, please check whether this is what you originally intended. The directories inside `project1` represent _crates_, whereas a _workspace_ is what you have at the root level.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How can I locate resources for testing with Cargo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30003921/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.