# How to get a crate's version number?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a crate with a version number declared in `Cargo.toml`. Is there any way to retrieve the version from inside the library?

Comment: This question already has an answer for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27840394/how-can-a-rust-program-access-metadata-from-its-cargo-package