# How to tell the version number of the Rust crate I'm in?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

Is there a robust way, maybe something in cargo CLI, to get the version of the crate?

I can grep on Cargo.toml, but I'm looking for something that won't break in 6 months.

Is there a better way?

Comment: What do you need this for? Have you tried `cargo tree --depth 0`?

Comment: Are you needing just a number (well a string, since a number cant have multiple periods) or are you fine with a tiny bit of extra data? `cargo pkgid` gives `files:///Users/sus/code/project#0.1.0`

Comment: There's also `cargo metadata`, but it is verbose and not geared to the current package if you're in a workspace.

Comment: If you need it in a build.rs script or embedded in an application, there's a [`CARGO_PKG_VERSION`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27840394/how-can-a-rust-program-access-metadata-from-its-cargo-package) environment variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest answer is

```bash
cargo pkgid
```

This outputs

```
files:///Users/sus/code/project#0.1.0
```

If you want this as just the version part, you can pipe this to `cut` (or handle it yourself in your programming language of choice)

```bash
cargo pkgid | cut -d "#" -f2
```

Answer (score 7):

The general way to get metadata about your package or workspace is via the [`cargo metadata`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-metadata.html) command, which produces a JSON output with your workspace packages, dependencies, targets, etc. However it is very verbose.

If you are not in a workspace, then you can simply get the version of the first package excluding dependencies (parsing with `jq`):

```
> cargo metadata --format-version=1 --no-deps | jq '.packages[0].version'
"0.1.0"
```

If you are in a workspace however, then there will be multiple packages (even after excluding dependencies) and appears to be in alphabetical order. You'd need to know the package's name:

```
> cargo metadata --format-version=1 --no-deps | jq '.packages[] | select(.name == "PACKAGE_NAME") | .version'
"0.1.0"
```

Comment: When using `jq` you might also want to use `--raw-output` to remove the quotes around the version number. Maybe would also be good to set `--exit-status` to fail if (for some reason) the version number could not be extracted. See also the [`jq` manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).